# Django performance issue with exclude

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have `word` model and `phrase` model

```
class Word(models.Model): 
        checked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Phrase(models.Model):
    words = models.ManyToManyField(Word, null=True,related_name = "phrases")
```

`Word` model has attribute `checked` and many to many connection to `phrase`

I have a query, something like this:

```
Phrase.objects.exclude(words__checked=True).filter(words__group__pk__in = groups_ids)
```

But it works really really slow on big datasets, and the problem is in exclude section, cause without it - it works fast enough
So I found a suggestion that I should use raw sql here,
[Performance issue with django exclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124053/performance-issue-with-django-exclude)

**So, how can rewrite this sentence with raw sql ?**

(I need this query to both work postgres and mysql due to requirements, or I will need two queries if one query can't achieve this, postgres query has more priority)

So far I 've tried to use .extra syntax,but it didn't work, so asking it here.

Comment: Did you try add `word__checked=False` to the filter?

Comment: @arcegk: the two are *not* the same. A filter means that you will JOIN, and simply obtain the `Phrase`s for which there is at least one `word_checked=False`, whereas `.exclude(word__checked=True)` will excude the *`Phrase`* from the moment *one* of the `word__checked=True`.